# angular fake API using jasonplaceholder, getting details after clicking button

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-services

I am working on a dummy API with jsonplaceholder, I am getting all posts after clicking button, but i wanna get userid and title on load,and after clicking title need to get that particular body of that id  How can i achieve this.

in jasonplaceholder there are 100 posts with id,title,body. on clicking getdata i need only id and title after when I click on title I need to get body as either in paragraph or popup or something.

html

```
    <button (click)="get()">Get Data</button>
<div class="col-md mt-4 mb-4">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>title</th>
        <th>body</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let d of data">
        <td><span>{{d.id}}</span></td>
        <td><span>{{d.title}}</span></td>
        <td><span>{{d.body}}</span></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

ts

```
get(){
    this.userservice.getData().subscribe((data) =>{
    console.log(data)
    this.data = data
    })
  }
```

service

```
getData():Observable<any>{
    const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
    return this.http.get(url)
   }
```

Comment: What is the issue, you are facing?

Comment: currently, there is no issue, but i need to get body when I click on id or title of that particular point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution would be to use *ngIf and a variable, eg. `selectedId`

```
<td (click)="showBody(d.id)"><span>{{d.title}}</span></td>
<td *ngIf="selectedId === d.id"><span>{{d.body}}</span></td>
```

Then in your component, initiate it:

```
selectedId: any = null;
```

and

```
showBody(id: number){
   this.selectedId ? this.selectedId = null : this.selectedId = id;
}
```

so that it would hide the body if you click on the title again.

Comment: im getting this error as         
Duplicate identifier 'showBody'. when im initiating     showBody: boolean = false;

Comment: Sorry, I just changed the variable name.

Comment: tnx for the update, but I need only that particular body which I selected, not all of the data. for example, if I clicked on title 3, the body of 3 should be displayed.

Comment: I changed my answer and hope that works, let me know

Comment: now it showing error as Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'number'. for both selectedId: number = null;     this.selectedId ? this.selectedId = null : this.selectedId = id;

Comment: or initiate it as 'any'.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you need to get the `id` of the element you clicked on it to show the element's `body`.

so to achive this, you can write something like this:

**component.html**

```html
<tr *ngFor="let d of data" (click)="setBody(d)">
    <td><span>{{d.id}}</span></td>
    <td><span>{{d.title}}</span></td>
</tr>

<!-- Show selected item body here -->
<h1>Selected item body</h1>
<p>{{selectedItemBody}}</p>
```

**component.ts file**

[Optional]: you can define the `POST` interface top of your ts file to have more clean code:

```
interface POST {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  body: string;
}
```

```
  setBody(post: POST) {
    this.selectedItemBody = post.body;
    alert(this.selectedItemBody); // you can remove this alert
  }
```

I provided you **[this sample working code here in stackblits](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-basic-starter-6lmasc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**